# Need help fading overlay with image-ads in and out - infitely

Tags: linux, bash, ffmpeg, streaming, youtube

Im trying overlay an image-ad every x-seconds, by fading the overlay in and out. It's a stream for our company in Southern Denmark.
Should be said im 3 days old in FFMPEG. And that its running on Ubuntu Server 22.04, which means ffmpeg 4.4.2. I was hoping somebody would be willing to help me out. :)))

**When i run the script, i get the videofeed, but the watermark disappears, and no image-ads are fading in. What i would like to happen is that the watermark, and textbanner are shown on top of the videofeed, and every=x seconds an image-ad fades in and overlays everything for x seconds, then fades away - repeats itself forever.**

Theres also som DTS-errors, but nothing that breaks the stream? Not sure what it is to be honest.

Im having trouble with a lot of things, so SHOOT if necessary !

I built this with help from a mid-to-high-level-experince linux user, but he knows nothing about ffmpeg. Im starting to understand FFMPEG. Im about ½ year-old in Linux :)))

Some words are in danish, e.g. tilbudstekst.txt - which mean Offerstext.txt.

This is my scipt:

```
#!/bin/bash

path=$(readlink -f "${0%/*}")
cd "$path"
echo "moved to the script folder $path"

# Input settings
input_url="rtsp://*:*@*:*/*"
input_args="-correct_ts_overflow 0 -fflags +discardcorrupt -fflags +genpts -deinterlace -color_range pc"

# Output settings
YOUTUBE_URL="rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2"           # RTMP-URL fra youtube
BACKUP_URL="rtmp://b.rtmp.youtube.com/live2?backup=1"   # BACKUP RTMP-URL fra youtube
KEY="****-****-****-****-****"                          # Streamkey fra YT
VBR="2500k"                                             # Bitrate
FPS="30"                                                # FPS
QUAL="medium"                                           # Preset - evt. se FFMPEG
output_args="-vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset $QUAL -tune zerolatency -r $FPS -g $(($FPS * 2)) -b:v $VBR -vsync 1 -acodec libmp3lame -ar 44100 -threads 4 -q:a 3 -b:a 712000 -bufsize 512k -af volume=0 -color_range pc"
output_filter="-f tee -map [out] -map 0:a -flags +global_header [f=flv]${YOUTUBE_URL}/${KEY}|[f=flv]${BACKUP_URL}/${KEY}"

# Advertisement settings
ad_duration=9
ad_fade_in=2
ad_fade_out=2
ad_wait_interval=10
ad_interval=$((ad_wait_interval+ad_fade_in+ad_fade_out+ad_duration))

# Watermark settings
watermark_path="./logo.jpg"
watermark_opacity="0.6"
watermark_filter="scale=200:200,format=rgba,colorchannelmixer=aa=$watermark_opacity"

# Text counter + speed settings
filename="tilbudstekst.txt"                             # Tæller antal tegn, og spytter et tal ind i variablen.
TEGN=$(wc -m < "$filename")
SF="0.3"                                                # Speed Faktor. Jo lavere, jo hurtigere bevæger teksten sig. Den kan bruges til at finjustere hastigheden på bannerteksten.
SPEED="($TEGN*$SF)"                                     # Hvor lang tid den den samlede besked tager at vise


# Text banner settings
text="./tilbudstekst.txt"
text_font_path="/usr/share/fonts/segoeuil.ttf"
text_font_size=120
text_font_color="black"
text_bg_color="white"
text_bg_opacity=0.6
text_bg_height="($text_font_size*1.2)"
text_filter="drawbox=0:(ih-$text_bg_height):iw:$text_bg_height:color=$text_bg_color@$text_bg_opacity:t=h, drawtext=textfile='$text':fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/segoeuil.ttf:x=w-mod(max(t-4.5\,0)*(w+tw)/$SPEED\,(w+tw)):y=(h-line_h-10):fontsize=$text_font_size:fontcolor=$text_font_color@$text_bg_opacity"

# main filter
main_scaler="scale=1920:1080"

# Advertisement filter
ad_scaler="scale=1920:1080"
ad_filter="loop=-1:size=$((ad_interval*FPS)),format=rgba,fade=in:st=0:d=$ad_fade_in:alpha=1,fade=out:st=$ad_duration:d=$ad_fade_out:alpha=1"
#ad_filter="format=rgba,loop=loop=0:size=$((ad_interval*FPS)),setpts=PTS-STARTPTS"

# Combine filters
filter=" \
[1:v]$watermark_filter[water]; \
[2:v]$ad_scaler, $ad_filter[ad]; \
[0:v]$main_scaler, $text_filter[main]; \
[main][water]overlay=20:20[main+water]; \
[main+water][ad]overlay=0:0[out]"


# Rename all files in folder to img%d.jpg (fortløbne numre)
img_dir="./billedeannoncer"
move_jpg(){
        i=1
        for img in $img_dir/*.jpg; do
                mv "$img" "$img_dir/img${i}.jpg"
                ((i++))
        done
}

while sleep 30; do move_jpg; done & while_move=$!
trap 'kill -9 $while_move' EXIT

ffmpeg $input_args -i $input_url -i $watermark_path -framerate 1/5 -i "$img_dir/img%d.jpg" \
    -filter_complex "$filter" \
    $output_args \
    ${output_filter}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

it is not a script:

```
ffmpeg \
-stream_loop -1 -t 300 -i "../all ok propoganda.mp4" \
-loop 1 -i "../logo.png" \
-framerate 4/10 -i "./billedeannoncer/%03d.jpg" \
-filter_complex "
[0:v]scale=1280:720,
drawbox=0:(ih-(120*1.2)):iw:(120*1.2):color=white@0.6:t=h,
drawtext=textfile='./tilbudstekst.txt'
:fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/segoeuil.ttf
:x=w-mod(max(t-4.5\,0)*(w+tw)/(14*0.3)\,(w+tw))
:y=(h-line_h-10)
:fontsize=120
:fontcolor=black@0.6[main];

[1:v]scale=200:200,
format=rgba,
colorchannelmixer=aa=0.6[water];

[2:v]scale=1280:720,
format=rgba,
fps=30,
fade=in:st=0:d=2,
fade=out:st=8:d=2[ad];

color=black@0:s=1280x720:r=30:d=90[blank];
[ad][blank]concat=n=2:v=1:a=0,loop=-1:size=30*100[ad];

[main][water]overlay=20:20:shortest=1[main+water];
[main+water][ad]overlay=0:0:shortest=1[out]
" -map [out] -map 0:a /tmp/out.mp4 -y
```

somehow it works for me :)

`-framerate 4/10` where 4 pics per 10 sec of duration of ad

`color=bla...:d=90` where 90 is duration of blank video

`loop=-1:size=30*100` where 30 is fps and 100 is duration of ad+blank

Comment: Just out of curiosity- what is concat? And why do you create [c] in the filter complex?

Comment: color is blank video, concat ad with blank video to get duration, for example, ad = 5 sec, interval 600 sec, then blank video will be 595 sec

Comment: i tried your code, but what i get is a quick flash of a semitransparent image every 5 seconds. Tried to adjust the timings as your described, but nothings changing. Ill be back..

Comment: If you have the time, I would appreciate a deeper explanation, again, if you have time and wouldn’t mind.

Comment: heres a link, so you can see what im dealing with - https://youtube.com/live/YuaBYPAnQc8?feature=share 

If you'd like to see my new code with your edits, let me know.

Comment: how many pics in `./billedeannoncer` dir? In my test 30 pics, so with `-framerate 5` duration is 30/5=6 sec, but I reduced to 5 sec with `-t 5` (idk why). Function `move_jpg()...` deletes files, so I removed it

Comment: Im not able to make it go past 20 seconds between ads, when the i set -framerate to show pictures for about 10 seconds?

Comment: if you have 30 pics, then 30pics/10sec=3fps, -> `-framerate 3`

Comment: i have 4 pictures = 30/4 = 0.133 - same result

Comment: 4pics/10sec=0.4fps `-framerate 4/10` or `-framerate 0.4`

Comment: im just not able to get it to work. If you wanted the pictures to fade-in for 10 seconds with 90 seconds between, what would you do? (i tried with -framerate 4/10 and 0,4..and a 100 other configs - no luck)

I have been struggling for way past 10 hours..

Comment: if 4 pics per 10 sec, then blank 90 sec -> `... -framerate 4/10 ... color=...d=90`

Comment: i've just copied your values, and sadly it does not work. The overlay with fade never shows.

Comment: This is what im seeing: https://youtube.com/live/jaytCbytOS4?feature=share

Comment: Do you tried my code? Add `echo` to line with `ffmpeg ...` in your code to see what is a difference

Comment: https://jpst.it/37n4_ <-- I think its exactly the same :-)

Comment: `img%00d.jpg` it is wrong, change to `img%d.jpg`. And this: `fade=out:st=8:d=2` because 8+2=10sec. Pics in my test has names 001.jpg 002.jpg etc. In your script they has names img1.jpg img2.jpg etc

Comment: https://youtube.com/live/Qf-V4mFezws?feature=share <-- Now its corrected to this: https://jpst.it/37nos

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/143110/discussion-on-answer-by---need-help-fading-overlay-with-image-ads); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.